# QGIS crashes with Sentinel-2 data

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, sentinel-2

I'm working with Sentinel-2 data in QGIS and after opening the product I zoom several times to have a look to the image and the program crashes. I'm using QGIS 2.18.10 on a Windows 10 mahcine. Any idea about this error?

M

Here some screenshots of the error:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The openjpeg2000 driver is quite bad. Did you try converting the data to another format? Did you try to use SNAP Toolbox from ESA?

Comment: Yes I tried SNAP but I would like to do all the process in QGIS. If I download the images with the Semi Automatic Classification plugin, they are converted to tiff ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCGM, yes SCP download any image to TIFF format. SNAP handling Sentinel 2 data in the best way, I also tried to work with it on QGIS and it didn't work well.
I suggest to try agains SNAP or ENVI to process your data and at the end convert it to a friendly GIS format.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it definitely works better when you work in GeoTIFF